# Replace non-duplicate character in string

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

HI I want to replace a forward slash by a space, but only if it appears once.

```
 str_replace_all( 'NOOOOO//ABCDEFGHI/asdfasd//sdkksksks', "/(?!=/)", " ")
```

Here I want the output to be: NOOOOO//ABCDEFGHI asdfasd//sdkksksks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following option with `sub`:

```
input <- "NOOOOO//ABCDEFGHI/asdfasd//sdkksksks"
gsub("(?<!/)/(?!/)", " ", input, perl=TRUE)

[1] "NOOOOO//ABCDEFGHI asdfasd//sdkksksks"
```

The strategy here is to use the pattern `(?<!/)/(?!/)`, which matches a single forward slash which it surrounded on both sides by anything other than another forward slash.

Comment: So "not a slash" can be represented in two ways in regex `!/` and `[^/]` ? Is the former perl specific ?

Comment: @RonakShah I'd say that `!/` is part of the negative look-behind, i.e. `(?<!text)` is the negation of a positive look-behind `(?<=text)`.

Comment: @RonakShah Only `[^/]` by itself means "not a slash."  `!/` only has meaning when part of a lookaround, e.g. `(?!/)` means "what follows is not a slash."

Comment: @RonakShah they are quite different lookarounds are zero length match they do not consume the word, where as character class do consume the word, `[^/]` means match anything which is not `/`, and on the other hand `some pattern(?!)` means `some pattern` should not be followed by `/`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using lookarounds, you could make use of [(*SKIP)(*FAIL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) using `sub`  with the option `perl=TRUE` to match the characters that should not be part of the match.

In this case you could match 2 or more forward slashes that should not be part of the match. After that, match a single forward slash to be replaced with a space.

```
/{2,}(*SKIP)(*F)|/
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sNwDcI/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/On5GSd)

For example

```
s <- "NOOOOO//ABCDEFGHI/asdfasd//sdkksksks"
gsub("/{2,}(*SKIP)(*F)|/", " ", s, perl=TRUE)
```

Output

```
[1] "NOOOOO//ABCDEFGHI asdfasd//sdkksksks"
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks - I wasn't even aware of SKIP/FAIL. I had been thinking of the look-around method but will certainly start using this construct.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use capture group

```
 (^|[^\/\n])\/([^\/\n]|$)
```

Than replace with `\1 \2`

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/Ij3bEo/1/)

Comment: Thanks, I got this to work using: str_replace_all(input, "(^|[^/])/([^/]|$)", "\\1 \\2").  Great pickup on the newline characters, although not relevant for me in this case, I can see that it generally would be.